# Lighting seems not to work in Eevee or cycles in 2.9

Tags: texturing, lighting

I'm a new user to blender only have bout 40 hours using the program and I'm having trouble with the render window where Cycle's lighting works but is somewhat unstable but seems to work while Eevee's lighting doesn't work at all I'll try to get back if you all need more information.
my specs are Radeon RX 590
an AMD ryzen 7 2700
and a Gigabyte B450M DS3H

Comment: You might want to use a few more periods in your question.  It helps the reader ... and eventually might help you. Your use of the word [unstable] could be strengthened with evidence.  Perhaps a Blender screen capture.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it sounds like you're suffering from the same problem many AMD card owners are having theses days. Roll back your graphics drivers to an earlier version- the latest Adrenalin drivers cause problems with blender.